# How can I stream big data to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am working on a system for analyzing data of any size and format streamed by the users to my private cloud based on Google Cloud Storage. Do you have any ideas how can I allow them to stream big data? At the moment I use Django API and I do this in this way:

```
def upload_blob(source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))
```

It works correctly with small files however when I send for example large movie I get the error shown below. I am aware that this is not the optimal solution but I have no idea how can I solve this. As you can notice at the moment they send me requests with the blob format but with very large files it does not work. Do you have any ideas how can I solve my problem and send users data of any size to Google Cloud Storage?

```
Internal Server Error: /cloud/
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
  chunked=chunked,
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
  conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
  self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
  self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
  self.send(chunk)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 987, in send
  self.sock.sendall(data)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1034, in sendall
  v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1003, in send
  return self._sslobj.write(data)
socket.timeout: The write operation timed out
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  timeout=timeout
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
  method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 400, in increment
  raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  raise value.with_traceback(tb)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
  chunked=chunked,
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
  conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
  self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
  self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
  self.send(chunk)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 987, in send
  self.sock.sendall(data)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1034, in sendall
  v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1003, in send
  return self._sslobj.write(data)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
  response = get_response(request)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
  return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
  return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
  response = self.handle_exception(exc)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
  self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
  raise exc
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
  response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/mypath/backend/views.py", line 635, in post
  'user/' + str(user_name) + '/' + str(file))
 File "/mypath/backend/views.py", line 214, in upload_blob
  blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1318, in upload_from_filename
  predefined_acl=predefined_acl,
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1263, in upload_from_file
  client, file_obj, content_type, size, num_retries, predefined_acl
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1173, in _do_upload
  client, stream, content_type, size, num_retries, predefined_acl
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1120, in _do_resumable_upload
  response = upload.transmit_next_chunk(transport)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/upload.py", line 425, in transmit_next_chunk
  retry_strategy=self._retry_strategy,
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/_helpers.py", line 136, in http_request
  return _helpers.wait_and_retry(func, RequestsMixin._get_status_code, retry_strategy)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_helpers.py", line 150, in wait_and_retry
  response = func()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 216, in request
  method, url, data=data, headers=request_headers, **kwargs
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
  resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
  r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
  raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out'))
[24/Mar/2020 19:17:26] "POST /cloud/ HTTP/1.1" 500 20879
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [**Resumable uploads**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads).

This option provides a resumable data transfer feature that lets you resume upload operations after a communication failure has interrupted the flow of data.

Especially useful if you are transferring large files, because the likelihood of a network interruption or some other transmission failures is high. In case of a failure, you do not have to restart large file uploads from the beginning when using this option.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the error message, you can see that the cause is a timeout. By default the timeout is 60 seconds, but you can specify a longer time. `blob.upload_from_filename(f'{filename}', timeout=300)` to wait for 300 seconds (or 5 minutes).